# Spring Boot Rest API How to get Client Information

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, http

I am writing a Rest API using spring framework which multiple clients (Web/Mobile) will use. In my API I want to know the client's info (client name) who is accessing it. What is the best practice to get the client name in API. Should I get it in http header or body?

Comment: Add it in the header and read the value after the user from the client has been authenticated.

Comment: But for authenticating the user I also need the information.

Comment: You read the headers after authenticating the user. After authenticating, you check if the client is of a particular type and proceed with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get information about the one accessing your endpoints, you must secure your endpoints and allow only authenticated users. 
This way you can get all the information you need about the user.
You can check spring security project for more details.

Comment: Consider this endpoint is a public endpoint like its signup where first time every client has to provide its information.

Comment: Do you want to access user's information in each endpoint in your api, or only when he sign up ?

Comment: I need it at the time of signup and later I can use JWT.

Comment: Then when the user sign up, send all the personal information that you need (first name, last name, email, phone ...) as body of the request